# Why does Vue think the string operations are a reactive data property?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

I'm using Vue and Vuetify. I have a reactive property that I want to do some text manipulation via a filter.:

```
filters: {
  shortenName(name) {
      return name.slice(0, 5);
}
```

And I use the filter like this:

```
{{name | shortenName}}
```

When I use this filter, I see an error that says `vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:1888 TypeError: Cannot read property 'slice' of undefined`.

This happens for any of the stock string methods such as toString(), substring(), etc.

Why does Vue think the string operations are a reactive data property?

Comment: `shortenName` is being called with `undefined` as an argument. Maybe adding a default parameter `shortenName(name = "")` should work if this data is being fetched asynchronously?

Comment: ah yes, that will do it. name is being fetched at an arbitrary point after the component mounts so your explanation makes sense

Comment: @adiga I've had these types of problems to many times, but I never thought of using default parameters, using v-if instead. This is definitely one of the most useful vue tips.